# Need to create python function that takes 3 values and works out max value and average of three numbers. My code is not running, not sure why

Tags: python

```
def numb(number1, number2, number3): 
    average = (number1 + number2 + number3)/3
    maxval = 0
    if number1 > number2:
       if number1 > number3:
            maxval = number1
            return maxval
       else:
            maxval = number3
            return maxval 
    elif number2 > number3:
            maxval = number2
            return maxval
    else:
            maxval = number3
            return maxval
    
    print("averag is: ", average)
    print("max value is: ", maxval)

number1 = int(input("enter a number: "))
number2 = int(input("enter a number: "))
number3 = int(input("enter a number: "))

numb(number1, number2, number3)
```

##Not sure what I'm doing, but the output is not running the function numb(number1, number2, number3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those `return` statements break the function prematurely

```
def numb(number1, number2, number3): 
    average = (number1 + number2 + number3)/3
    maxval = 0
    if number1 > number2:
       if number1 > number3:
            maxval = number1
       else:
            maxval = number3
    elif number2 > number3:
            maxval = number2
    else:
            maxval = number3
    
    print("averag is: ", average)
    print("max value is: ", maxval)

number1 = int(input("enter a number: "))
number2 = int(input("enter a number: "))
number3 = int(input("enter a number: "))

numb(number1, number2, number3)
```